# Continuously output from StandardOutput to text box in Visual C#

Tags: textbox, stdout, visual-c#-express-2010

How do I continuously send the output from StandardOutput of a process (java) to a multiline textbox while still being able to use the rest of the form? There must be a way to do this but I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: This looks different - are Console Output and Standard Output the same thing?

Comment: It looks different, but I think what you want to achieve is the same thing. Console output can be a combination of standard output and standard error. But anyway, with the code in the answer demonstrated there, you should be able to capture the output in real-time